# Firebase push notification data handling while the app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am trying to setup firebase push notification for my webview android app. My target is, i will send a url in the notification and it will open in the app. here is my problem.

following is the php code im using to send the message

```
<?php

// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'XXXXX' );
$id='XXXXXX';
$registrationIds = array($id);
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
'body'  => 'Your post has received a reply',
'title'     => 'Title of the post here',
);

$data = array
(
        'url'=>'http://XXXXXXXX.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=21421#p21421'

);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'notification'          => $msg,
    'data'          => $data

);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;
```

And this is my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService$NotificationBar" />

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

and this is my receiver

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static String url;
    public static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        url = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");
        Log.d(TAG, "URL: " + url);

    }
    public class NotificationBar extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_bar);

        }
    }
}
```

from here i pass the url to main activity. Now the problem is, if the app is in foreground and i send a message, i can see the url in the log. 
But when the app is in background and i send a message, i only see the notification in the status and nothing in the log. if i tap on the notification, it just open the app without passing the url.

could you please help? please be as detail as possible as i have almost zero idea about android programming.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see explanation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

> `onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background**. In
>   this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray.
>   A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
>   foreground.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>   device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your launcher Activity.

You should check for data payload in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity which means if `HomeActivity` is your launcher activity in manifest you should check inside `HomeActivity's` `onCreate` method:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    ...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!